# Access WAMP, different internet connections

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I want a certain person to access my PHP program (connected to a MySQL database) but we live in different places. Is it possible for her to access my Wamp Server if we are connected to different internet connections? I got it to work with someone but we were connected to the same WiFi.

Comment: how about using Teamviewer

Comment: across the internet, look into dynamic dns, unless you have a static ip. On lan, use your firewall to allow connections to to your computers webserver

Comment: When you say _access my PHP program_ Do you mean a `web page` or `web site`

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one connection between both LAN network either LAN or WAN.
You need to edit apache config file vhost access permission to "Allow from All".
Once you do that go to server's network router and forward all port 80,443 and 3306 traffic to wamp server's IP address it.
Now you can access wamp server directly by using WAN IP of server's network.

Answer (score 0):

You'd basically have two options to make it visible to her:

1. Make your web server visible from the Internet which has lots of
   security implications and might require you to use a custom port
   since most ISPs block incoming requests on port 80.  You would have to set up port forwarding in your router to point to your web server.
2. Set up a VPN server that she could connect to, which would also need to be port forwarded in your router.  This also has security implications but would likely result in much fewer attacks.